# Can't Set Up MySQL Connection: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

was trying to connect to mysql server with spring boot but getting this error: **com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required**

**application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=shafin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

i am using sqlyog and wamp server.

**gradle.build file:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
}
```

i am giving all required authentication info correctly, still getting this error.

Comment: Does this help? https://support.datameer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002831151-Can-t-Set-Up-MySQL-Connection-CLIENT-PLUGIN-AUTH-is-required Check the versions of your `mysql-connector-java` dependency and `spring.datasource.driver-class-name`, if connector is version 6 and up then `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` value should be `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` and not `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` as you have

Comment: tried that but it did not helped...